# Bootstrap Validation Message Shows Up In The Wrong Place

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I have created an ASP.NET user input form using Bootstrap with the following HTML fragment:

```
          <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSignIn" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Set Up Your Member Account
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ddSalutation" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                        How Do We Greet You?
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddSalutation" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="tbFirstName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                        First Name:
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="tbFirstName"
                                            required placeholder="Enter your first name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="tbMiddleName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                        Middle Name/Initial:
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="tbMiddleName"
                                            required placeholder="Enter your middle name/initial">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="tbLastName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                        Last Name:
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input type="text" runat="server" class="form-control" id="tbLastName"
                                            required placeholder="Enter your last name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="tbPhone" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                        Contact Telephone:
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <input type="tel" title="Telephone Number" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" 
                                            id="tbPhone" placeholder="Telephone" class="form-control" 
                                            required runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="tbSSN" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                                        SSN/Tax ID Number:
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <input type="text" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$"
                                            title="Social Security Number" runat="server" class="form-control" id="tbSSN"
                                            required placeholder="SSN/Tax ID">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-7" id="buttons">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="Server"
                                            Text="Next"
                                            CssClass="btn btn-default btn-sm col-sm-4"
                                            OnClick="btnNext_Click"></asp:Button>
                                        <button type="reset" id="btnReset" class="btn btn-default btn-sm col-sm-4">
                                            Reset Form</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="text-center" id="divProcessing" style="display: none;">
                            <img src="images\loading.gif" style="height: 40px; width: 40px;" />&nbsp;Please wait...
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger fade col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 text-center" id="lblStatus">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The form lays out just fine.  The problem is, when I click the button to process the form, the validation messages from Bootstrap don't line up with the fields that need attention from the user.  Here's a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

As you can see, the form field that needs attention is the first name field, but the tooltip popup from Bootstrap is down to the lower right.  I don't have any malformed HTML, so I don't understand what the problem is with the positioning of the popup message.  Any help on this?  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a validation message from Bootstrap, this is your browser's inbuilt validation checking (unless you are using some validation script you're not telling us about). Bootstrap doesn't come with validation out of the box, only the ability to add classes that show validation errors. Try it in a couple of different browsers and see if the behaviour differs. Then it might be worth seeing if you can recreate the problem in a jsFiddle that we can look at ourselves.

Comment: For the sake of 2 minutes I created a jsFiddle. I see no problem in Chrome, and Firefox and IE don't seem to do the validation anyway - http://www.bootply.com/CoGRPGY55N

Comment: The question is, with Chrome, why does the validation popup show so far down the page from the field where the error is encountered?  The CSS and HTML don't show a problem, so I don't get it.  In the MS Edge browser, it shows a dialog below the field where the issue is, which is acceptable, but Chrome positions it down toward the bottom of the form instead of below or alongside the field being validated.

Comment: That is odd, considering the bootply works fine. Could be something to do with other elements on your page. Try stripping away all the extra parts of your site (like containers, headers etc.) until you are just left with the form. If it hasn't fixed itself by the time you are down to just the form, try removing any of your custom css and see if it fixes itself. You should slowly be able to narrow down the problem to one awkward class of odd container.

Comment: I couldn't get to the root of this issue, so I ended up switching to a modal window that show the field(s) which require attention for validation.  It actually works out better that way, I think.  Thanks for your advice though, @Rob.